# Nested queries from multiple Oracle databases

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, subquery

In .NET, Is it possible to run a nested query from two separate Oracle databases?

E.g.

"SELECT my_value,
 FROM table_in_database_1
 WHERE my_value IN ( SELECT my_value 
                     FROM table_in_database_2 )"

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Ultimately, this is an effort to overcome an "ORA-01795" error from using an "in" statement with over 1000 items in the conditional list, without having to break the query out into multiple "OR value IN" lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with simply building a database link and joining over that link, but that can have performance issues. Something like this:

Build a link to database 2 on database 1.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK db2 CONNECT TO user IDENTIFIED BY pw USING tns-alias;
```

Join your table on database 1 to the table on database 2:

```
SELECT my_value 
  FROM table_in_database_1 t1 JOIN table_in_database_2@db2 t2
       ON t1.my_value = t2.my_value
```

Depending on the performance of the link, you may opt to use a hybrid approach for this, involving both a database link and a temporary table.

Build a database link as above. Build a temporary table on database 1 that holds the values to be used in the subquery from database 2.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE db2_values (value VARCHAR2(20));
```

Copy the values from db2 to db1:

```
INSERT INTO db2_values
SELECT my_value 
  FROM table_in_database_2@db2;
```

Finally, join your database 1 table to the temporary table.

```
SELECT my_value
  FROM table_in_database_1 t1 JOIN db2_values t2 ON t1.my_value = t2.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make a database link, you can also insert into a temp table in database_1 all values from  `SELECT my_value FROM table_in_database_2` and after that make the join.

Comment: How would you get the data from database 2 into database 1 without the link?

Comment: @Dcookie - you could do it in the front-end if you had to.  Execute query against database 2; insert that data into a table in database 1; execute query against database 1.

Comment: Dave Costa is right, read the last sentence; he execute querys against both databases; he has two connections :)

Comment: I'll take your word for it ;-) So, what you'd wind up doing is selecting the db2 list into your program, then inserting it into db1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can look into Database Links for this.